# bloom-release "pull request modifies a repository entry other than the one being released"

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Trying to release a new version (0.0.5) of `ament_virtualenv` for `dashing`, `bloom-release ament_virtualenv --rosdistro dashing --track dashing` aborted with the following message:

```
This generated pull request modifies a repository entry other than the one being released.
This likely occurred because the upstream rosdistro changed during this release.
This pull request will abort, please re-run this command with the -p option to try again.
```

- I tried again with `-p`, but it fails every time.
- I deleted everything in `/tmp` and tried again from scratch but it fails again with the same message.
- I released it for `crystal` and **that worked without problems**.
- I tried again for `dashing` and get the same error again.
- I tried searching for solutions/answers but could not find any.

Does anybody have an idea as to what causes this?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341427/bloom-release-%22pull-request-modifies-a-repository-entry-other-than-the-one-being-released%22/) by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-01-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-10**:
It would help if you could show us the command line you tried to use.

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2020-01-10**:
Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please update your python-rosdistro package. The change was introduced in here: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdistro/pull/147

Package is available via debians or pip

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2020-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-10**:
@Karsten: did you run into this error yourself and is that why you recognise it?

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2020-01-10**:
that is correct. I am currently on version 0.8.0 of `rosdistro` and this seemed to help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-10**:
It's rather unfortunate that a seemingly unrelated change results in these kinds of errors. The error message does not give any clue as to what the problem really is.

Was this breakage considered when that PR was merged?

**Comment by [max-krichenbauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/44322/max-krichenbauer/) on 2020-01-10**:
Thanks a lot! That indeed solved it!